# Alternate row colors with exceptions

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with some rows hidden. I do show them, but on demand. A user must perform an action to display those rows. Each hidden rows has class="hideMe" withing TR tag.

I would like to add a class to alternating rows, to change color, but only to those that are always visible. Normally it's simple, but I'm not sure how incorporate hidden rows exception.

```
$('.myTable tr:odd:not(hideMe)').addClass('altRow');
```

Can it be done with just CSS or do I need to throw in some jQuery magic?

Comment: So when the "hidden" rows are displayed, you do not want them to have the striping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, tweaking just "a little" your code, you get a nice solution:

```
$('.myTable tr:not(.hideMe):odd').addClass('altRow');
```

See it working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/HYHWJ/

Another solution would be :

```
$('.myTable tr:not(.hideMe)')
  .removeClass('altRow')
  .filter(':odd')
  .addClass('altRow');
```

See this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/r4N5g/

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to resort to JavaScript:

```
$('.myTable tr:not(.hideMe)').each(function (i) {
    $(this).toggleClass( 'altRow', !! (i % 2) );
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PxT93/

---

For [a *tiny* increase in performance](http://jsperf.com/modulo-vs-bit-wise), you could use the `&` bit-wise operator instead of the modulo:

```
$('.myTable tr:not(.hideMe)').each(function (i) {
    $(this).toggleClass( 'altRow', !! (i & 1) );
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PxT93/1/

Comment: Throw in an else in there to removeClass for rows that were previously `altRow` but are no longer so because of the newly displayed rows. :-)

Comment: @MichaelMarr - I'm assuming the OP knows how to do that, but I added it to my answer. For you :)

Comment: See, isn't that answer much more elegant now? :-)